# Javascript comparison operators, is === more efficient than ==?

Tags: javascript, performance

I recently was told the triple equal operator is more efficient because it will not try and convert any of the variables before comparing. Never thought about performance implications.

Does anyone have information on the performance of various comparison operators or other common JS operators that may slow a framework down?

Are there complex object types where this is a factor?

I realize this may be relevant to edge cases only, but without concrete data, it's hard to tell.

Comment: ... when microseconds are important to you :p

Comment: Similar to almost all of these microbenchmark "this simple trick can improve your performance!" snakeoil stories: not worth your time, won't be the bottleneck of your program. Typically even worse, refactoring code to conform to these things often makes it less readable, causing things which then are a real bottleneck (due to programming flaws, caused by bad readability)

Answer (score 1):

Should be, since it performs less operations. `==` performs type conversions before comparing if both arguments have different types. Pseudocode below.

```
function doubleEquals(a, b) {
  [a, b] = coerceTypes(a, b)
  return compareSameType(a, b)
}

function tripleEquals(a, b) {
  if (!areSameType(a, b)) {
    return false
  }
  return compareSameType(a, b)
}
```

If you compare `==` and `===` with two inputs of the same type though, the difference should be very small to none since no conversion would be required.

Answer (score -1):

This is not really an answer to my question, but only one edge example:

For 100K or more comparisons between a string and a float (ex: 0.035 == "0.035") it seems there is certainly a noticeable performance difference of around 1000%, or 10x. As tested on Chrome v77.

If there is a framework doing a lot of comparisons behind the scenes, I could see how this could effect how "crisp" it feels. But it could also be completely irrelevant. I don't have any data for framework use.

See the code below for a an example.

```
print('string vs float comparison operator performance')
let start = Date.now();
let loopCount = 10000000;
let appxLoopCostRatio = 2857;

for (let i=0; i < loopCount; i++) {
  let x = Math.random();
  let y = Math.random().toString();
  if (x == y) count++;
}

let mid = Date.now();

for (let i=0; i < loopCount; i++) {
  let x = Math.random();
  let y = Math.random().toString();
  if (x === y) count++;
}

let mid2 = Date.now();

//no comparison
for (let i=0; i < loopCount; i++) {
  let x = Math.random();
  let y = Math.random().toString();
}

let finish = Date.now();

let a, b, cost;
a = mid-start;
b = mid2-mid;
cost = finish-mid2;
print('runtime == comparison:', mid-start);
print('runtime === comparison:', mid2-mid);
print('appx cost of variable generation:', finish-mid2);
let expectedCost = (loopCount / appxLoopCostRatio);
let TcCost = (b-cost < (expectedCost * 0.05)) ? (expectedCost * 0.05) : b-cost;
print(` === is more efficient by ${Math.floor((a-cost)/TcCost) * 100 }%`)
```

Comment: results of tests like this are very not predictable since lots of things can be hapening under the hood. JS runtimes compile and optimize code "in place" through many stages. The level of optimization each compiler is able to achieve (or decided to achieve) and the compilation time itself may take into account